# Converting hex to binary and binary to decimal

Tags: java, hex, decimal

I need to read a text file with few lines of hex (e.g. 014ADC68F). I need to convert those into binary. Once it's all converted the binary then needs to be converted to decimal. The tricky part is that parsing cannot be used.

I've tried looking up some help, but all the examples either use parsing or are from a hex that was written with scanner.

I've only kept the opening of the files and restarted reset everything because nothing was working for me. This is in Java.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parsing cannot be used"? Can you show us an example of a solution that worked, but violated that rule? Also, you say that your solution doesn't work. Can you show us your solution and describe in what way it is failing to meet your needs?

Comment: Using something like this cannot be used: int decimal = Integer.parseInt(hexadecimal, 16);. It has to be manually done like: if (int = 0) binary = 0000 and so on. I can't figure out how to convert it when reading it from a file.